# ProcessBuilder on a jar package in an executable jar as resources

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

My java uses `ProcessBuilder` to run several commands using `other jar` that I have added in the resources.

It works fine in Eclipse, but once I export it to `executable jar`, it doesn't work:

```
//Defs Class has this line
public final static String APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH = Defs.class.getResource("/apktool.jar").getPath();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", Defs.APKTOOLS_JAR_PATH, "d", apkPath, "-o", decodePath, "-f");
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

I get back:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile apktool.jar
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: "it doesn't work". Please [edit] your question to describe specifically how it's failing. Is it producing any error messages? What do they say?

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh I have a added error description

Comment: @Kenster I updated the question

Comment: A full stacktrace is always helpful for us to understand the error.Provide it all..

Comment: @GoXR3Plus nothing else is printed, That is the whole error. It just can't point to the jar or can't access it

Answer (score 1):

The Java command executable cannot read a jar file from a jar file. It can only read from the file system. You would have to write the contents of that jar file into a temp file and pass that pathname to the `ProcessBuilder`.